# Passing a function as value of object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using reactjs.

I want to pass an `action` array to my component. My action is like this:

```
const actions = [
                 {
                   'action':'delete',
                   'on':'id',
                   'onClick':this.delete()
                 },
                 {
                   'action':'detail',
                   'on':'id',
                   'onClick':this.detail()
                 }
                ]

<MyComponent actions={actions}/>
```

but I don't know if it is possible to pass a function to component inside objects.

**updated**

Now how to pass parameter? I want to pass parameter from `MyComponent` to parent component.

Comment: remove the `()`, use it as  `onClick:this.delete`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can pass the function inside a object but you should not call. try this

```
let action ={
    delete:{
        on:'id',
        onClick:this.delete.bind(this)
    },
    details:{
        on:'id',
        onClick:this.detail.bind(this)
    }
}
<MyComponent actions={actions}/>
```

If you want to pass variable from child to parent then use a lambda function

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button onclick={e=>{
                //here you can pass any param from child to parent
                let params={}; //your params
                this.props.actions.delete(params);
            }}>Delete</button>

            <button onclick={e=>{
                //here you can pass any param from child to parent
                let params={}; //your params
                this.props.actions.detail(params);
            }}>Details</button>
            </div>
        )
    }

}
```

Comment: `params is not defined`, I want to pass params from`MyComponent` to parent component.

Comment: I have changed the format of actions variable. and provided the example for the child component. @S.M_Emamian

Answer (score 2):

The () will call your function, try:

```
      const actions = [
        {
          'action':'delete',
          'on':'id',
          'onClick':this.delete
        },
        {
          'action':'detail',
          'on':'id',
          'onClick':this.detail
        },
      ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are loosing the context so `this` is not recognized.
Maybe you should do this:

```
    const actions = [
    {
      'action':'delete',
      'on':'id',
      'onClick':(() => this.delete(params))
    },
    {
      'action':'detail',
      'on':'id',
      'onClick':(() => this.detail(params))
    },
  ]

<MyComponent actions={actions}/>
```

Comment: unnecessary wrapping

Comment: I converted the function to arrow function so the 'this' will be binded